# I want to access my array(which is in return()) inside a setup() methods method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

Here I have an array named `Title` in `data()` which is returning my array *(values are getting added dynamically)* and I want to access that `Title` array in the `onDrop()` method inside `setup()`, but it says it is `undefined`. Can anyone help me with this error.

```js
import Home from "./components/Home.vue";
import Section from "./components/Sections.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Home,
    Section,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      Title: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sectionTitle(Title) {
      const newSectionTitle = {
        Title: Title,
      };
      this.Title.push(newSectionTitle);
    },
    onremoveSection(Index) {
      this.Title.splice(Index, 1);
    },
  },
  setup() {
    const startDrag = (event, index) => {
      console.log(index);
      event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
      event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
      event.dataTransfer.setData("TitleIndex", index);
    };
    const onDrop = (event, indx) => {
      console.log(indx);
      const index = event.dataTransfer.getData("TitleIndex");
      console.log(index);

      let indexToMoveFrom = index;
      let indexToMoveTo = indx;
      const shifter = (Title, indexToMoveFrom, indexToMoveTo) => {
        let buff = Title[indexToMoveFrom];
        for (let i = indexToMoveFrom; i < indexToMoveTo; i++) {
          Title[i] = Title[i + 1];
        }
        Title[indexToMoveTo] = buff;
        console.log(Title);
      };

      shifter(Title, indexToMoveFrom, indexToMoveTo);
    };
    return {
      startDrag,
      onDrop,
    };
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move your data and methods to setup function:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Home,
    Section,
  },
  setup() {
    const title = ref([])
    const sectionTitle = (Title) => {
      const newSectionTitle = {
        Title: Title,
      };
      title.value.push(newSectionTitle);
    }
    const onremoveSection = (Index) => {
      title.value.splice(Index, 1);
    }
    const startDrag = (event, index) => {
      console.log(index);
      event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
      event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
      event.dataTransfer.setData("TitleIndex", index);
    };
    const onDrop = (event, indx) => {
      console.log(indx);
      const index = event.dataTransfer.getData("TitleIndex");
      console.log(index);

      let indexToMoveFrom = index;
      let indexToMoveTo = indx;
      const shifter = (Title, indexToMoveFrom, indexToMoveTo) => {
        let buff = Title[indexToMoveFrom];
        for (let i = indexToMoveFrom; i < indexToMoveTo; i++) {
          Title[i] = Title[i + 1];
        }
        Title[indexToMoveTo] = buff;
        console.log(Title);
      };

      shifter(Title, indexToMoveFrom, indexToMoveTo);
    };
    return {
      title,
      startDrag,
      onDrop,
      sectionTitle,
      onremoveSection
    };
  },
};

</script>
```